# Java Mysql Nullpointer exception

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, prepared-statement

I am trying to feed data into a MySQL table using a `PreparedStatement`, the problem is that I get a `NullPointerException` when it reaches the `pst.setInt` line.

```
    Conexion con = new Conexion();
    Connection reg = con.conexion();
    Integer ced;
    boolean f = false;        

    String nom, ape, email, dir, tel, codtel, telefono;
    Date fechareg = new Date();
    String sql;

    ced = Integer.getInteger(CedulaField.getText());
    nom = NombreField.getText();
    ape = ApellidoField.getText();
    email = emailField.getText();
    dir = dirArea.getText();
    tel = TelField.getText();
    codtel = (String) TelBox.getSelectedItem();
    telefono = codtel + tel;        

    tel = TelField.getText();
    sql = "INSERT INTO estudiantes (cedula, nombre, apellido, email, direccion, telefono, fecha_registro) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = reg.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1,ced);
        pst.setString(2,nom);
        pst.setString(3,ape);
        pst.setString(4,email);
        pst.setString(5,dir);
        pst.setString(6,telefono);
        pst.setDate(7, (java.sql.Date) fechareg);

        //if (f == false){
            int n = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (n > 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"registrado con exito");
            }
        //}
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ingreso_Datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al registrar");
    }
```

Here is my estudiantes table

```
cedula          | int(11) unsigned zerofill | NO | PRI | NULL
nombre          | varchar(50)               | NO |     | NULL
apellido        | varchar(50)               | NO |     | NULL 
email           | varchar(100)              | NO |     | NULL
direccion       | varchar(100)              | NO |     | NULL 
telefono        | varchar(11)               | NO |     | NULL 
fecha_registro  | timestamp                 | NO |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

If I am giving `ced` a value, why am I getting a `NullPointerException`? The `cedula` is an id that has a number that's unique to every registered citizen, so I was planning to use it as a primary key. What am i doing wrong?

David Maust pointed out the difference between **Integer.getInteger and Integer.parseInt** that was were the problem was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did you notice that your table allows NULL values for the `cedula` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this line is returning `null`.

```
ced = Integer.getInteger(CedulaField.getText());
```

According to the javadoc this method retrieves the value of the system property by name. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger(java.lang.String)

I think you meant to use is `parseInt`, which parses the string as an integer:

```
ced = Integer.parseInt(CedulaField.getText());
```